# Drupal WebForm With PinPointe--Avoid Confirmation Page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Our company uses PinPointe for email marketing and we have a Drupal 6 site with several language domains. I have created a web form except I did not create any fields in Drupal. Instead in the node Edit **NOT THE NODE WEBFORM EDIT**....in the node edit for the body section I added the HTML and the javascript for form. Everything works well and the data is captured to pinpointe. The problem lies in the fact that the page..upon clicking submit..actually redirects to PinPointe where I get a friendly message saying. Thanks for joining. Well I don't want this. I would like to just pop an alert saying thanks and leave the user on the page they were on. I tried this code for using jquery to do the post but it isn't loading and I suspect that's because I need it in the header not the body.

So all I want is to submit the data to pinpointe and not redirect the user. So here is where my limited Drupal knowledge runs out:

1. If I create the input fields in the node webform then how do I get the form to post to pinpointe?
2. If I create the fields dynamically in the node body (not node>>webform) I can direct the submission to PinPointe but then how do I stop the redirect?

FWIW here is the jquery I was trying to use but suspect has to go in the header http://jsfiddle.net/4xDFK/4/

FWIW here is the code for the dynamic creation:

```
<form action="http://na04.mypinpointe.com/...." id="webform-client-form-1375" method="post" onsubmit="return CheckForm257(this);">
    <div>
        <div id="webform-component-UsrEmail">
            <div id="edit-submitted-UsrEmail-wrapper">
                <input id="edit-submitted-UsrEmail" name="email" size="30" type="email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">
            <input class="form-submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" type="submit" value=" " />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your custom confirmation page in Drupal. Then set up PinPointe to redirect to this confirmation page.

In the PinPointe form manager, there is a option under the 'Thank you page options' to send a signup user to a custom URL.

Comment: Yes but what if I don't want a redirect at ALL! Say Jquery submits the form and simply pops an alert('Thx'); and the page never changes.

Comment: See this SO question on how to submit form data with jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772839/jquery-post-form-data. In Drupal, you can just add the jQuery code to a .js file in your theme.