# Sweatalert2 is not working properly inside the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using sweatalert2, when the form submitted sweatalert2 is coming but it closing with any press button (OK button) it close very fast. but when I use in a simple button without the form, it's working properly.

```js
const sweatalert = () => {
  return Swal('Good job!','You clicked the button!','success')
}
```

```html
<!-- Include sweet alert 2. -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.32.4/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input 
    type="submit" 
    name="addrecord" 
    class="btn btn-primary" 
    onclick="sweatalert()" 
    style="margin-left:100px;"
    value="Add Record"
  />
</form>

<!-- Just here for visual purpose. -->
<hr/>
  
<p>Out side the form is OK.</p>
<input 
  type="submit" 
  name="addrecord" 
  class="btn btn-primary" 
  onclick="sweatalert()" 
  style="margin-left:100px;" 
  value="Add"
/>
```

Comment: fyi, it's _sweetalert2_

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the form is submitting when you click the button. This means the page will refresh, and remove the alert generated. You can use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the submission from happening. You also need to make sure you pass the `event` through in your `onclick` callback:

`onclick="sweatalert(event)"`

See example below:

```js
function sweatalert(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop default functionality of submission (ie. page refresh and data post)
  swal(
    'Good job!',
    'You clicked the button!',
    'success'
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <button type="submit" name="addrecord" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sweatalert(event)" style="margin-left:100px;">Add Record</button>
</form>
```

However, do note: This will stop the submission of the form occurring. If you want to submit the form and then display the alert after submitting your data to PHP you should use AJAX. If you use jQuery you can use `$.post` or `$.ajax` methods to send your data to PHP, and then use a callback function which will be called if your data was submitted successfully.

Comment: now, it's working but the form is not submitting, I am using jquery with php, so what I must do even I changed the method method=$.post but it's not working and also how to make the callback function.

Comment: @Ahmad that in itself is quite a big question. I suggest you do some research on how to use `$.post` with PHP. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772839/jquery-post-form-data) question and answer for more clarification and see jQuery's [\$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) docs.

Answer (score 0):

Swal returns a promise. Hence you need to prevent the default submit event and use [.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) where you can  [submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) the form:

```js
const sweatalert = (ele, evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    Swal('Good job!','You clicked the button!','success').then((result) => {
                ele.closest('form').submit();  // get the closest form and submit
            });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.32.4/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>


<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input
            type="submit"
            name="addrecord"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            onclick="sweatalert(this, event)"  
            style="margin-left:100px;"
            value="Add Record"
            />
</form>
```